# Maximal height of subgroups in $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

In the process of solving some exercise, I became curious about the maximum height of a chain of subgroups in $S_n$.

More specifically - what is the maximum length k of a chain of subgroups $\{e\} \subset H_1 \subset \ldots \subset H_k = S_n$, where no additional conditions are imposed on the subgroups other than the inclusions being proper.

Does anyone know any results in this direction? It feels somewhat beyond my current abilities.

My google searches for maximal series connected me to results about composition series, chief series, which I am already familiar with. Is there some reason why a maximal series of subgroups (in a finite group) is uninteresting in general? (I guess they are certainly less interesting than their normal series cousins, since the difference between successive terms cannot be measured by a group...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's clearly bounded by the number of primes dividing $n!$, counting multiplicity (i.e., the order of each subgroup in the chain is a prime times the order of the previous subgroup). This is achieved for at least $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5$.

Also, since $S_{n-1}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, if you can show that there's a chain of subgroups between $S_{n-1}$ and $S_n$ where each extension is of prime degree, then by induction, this bound is achieved by every $S_n$.

Comment: Adding to @Nishant's comment, one can say that the series stops at $S_6$: The only subgroup of $S_6$ with index smaller than $6$ is $A_6$, and $A_6$ does not have any subgroup of index smaller than $6$ (both follows from $A_6$ being simple). On the other hand the biggest prime dividing the order of $S_6$ is 5. This can be generalized to all non-prime $n>5$. (In particular the chain hoped for in the last sentence of Nishant's comment does not exist for $n>5$.)

Comment: Why does the simplicity of $A_6$ prevent there from being a subgroup of index $3$?

Comment: @Nishant: Let $S_6$ act on the cosets of that subgroup of index 3 and restrict the action to $A_6$. How does this action of $A_6$ look like?

Comment: There's a homomorphism from $A_6$ to $S_3$, and it's not injective since the order of $S_3$ is too small, so the action is trivial. Thus, this subgroup is contained in $A_6$, which contradicts Lagrange?

Comment: @Nishant: Your last sentence is the wrong way round: "Thus, this subgroup contains $A_6$, which contradicts that it has a smaller order than $A_6$."

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This value is known.  The length of the longest subgroup chain in $S_{n}$ is given by
$$\left\lceil\frac{3n}{2}\right\rceil - b(n) - 1,$$
where $b(n)$ is the number of $1$s in the base $2$ representation of $n$.

**Reference:** P.J. Cameron, R. Solomon and A. Turull, Chains of subgroups in symmetric groups, *J. Algebra* 127 (1989), 340-352.

There is also an earlier paper:

**Reference:** L. Babai, On the length of subgroup chains in the symmetric group, *Comm. Algebra* 14 (1986), 1729-1736,

in which the upper bound $2n-1$ is established.

One reason why such a longest chain is interesting is that its length provides a bound on the minimal number of generators for any subgroup.  In particular, for the case of $S_{n}$, the bound above provides an upper bound for the minimal number of generators of any permutation group of degree $n$.

Comment: I can safely say I never would have expected this to be the exact value!  Amazing.  (Also, notationally: I don't know how standard it is, but Knuth uses $\nu(n)$ for the function you call $b(n)$.  There are many, many notations for this function, though...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki.  Agreed, it is amazing.  The proof is quite delicate, and uses the CFSG.

Comment: How does the length of a chain bound the number of generators for a subgroup?

Comment: @Nishant Suppose that the maximal chain length is $\ell$.  If a subgroup $H$ is generated minimally by $\{h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_m\}$, then $\langle h_1\rangle\leq\langle h_1,h_2\rangle\leq\cdots\leq\langle h_1,h_2,\ldots, h_m\rangle$ forces $m\leq\ell$.

Comment: @James Thanks. Indeed bounding the necessary number of generators of a subgroup of $S_n$ was why I became interested in this question in the first place.

Comment: @James It uses the China Fire and Security Group? ;)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Apologies; I guess I ought not to have taken for granted that "CFSG" would be a familiar abbreviation.  It is short for the [classification of the finite simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups).

Comment: @James I was only kidding, of course I knew what you meant. But perhaps that helps other people.